# How to highlight a specific range of cells if none have a value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Apologies in advance if I don't explain this very well, I have only an amateur's interest in formulas.

I have a Google Sheet where I need to fill in a value, in this case, "1" in one column in the range C-J for each row.

I'd like to know the custom formula so that if I haven't filled in a "1" in any row C-J, then the C-J range of that row is highlighted red (but not the whole row)

I've attached screenshots of what it looks like currently and then an example of what I would like it to look like.

Current:

[image: Screenshot of Current Sheet]

Desired:

[image: Screenshot of Desired Sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this custom formula:

```
=SUM($C4:J4)=0
```

[image: 0]

or you can use:

```
=COUNTIFS($C4,"",$D4,"",$E4,"",$F4,"",$G4,"",$H4,"",$I4,"",$J4,"")
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Formula

```
=countif($C2:$J2,1)=0
```

[image]